# Transitive equivalent of "drag on"

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

I know that we can use "drag on" for something that is progressing slowly or lasts longer than expected. For example:

*The meeting dragged on for 5 hours.*

Is there any way to make this transitive? Something like :

*The boss dragged on the meeting as long as he could so that we miss the train.*

I am trying to say that the boss made the meeting last longer only because he wanted us to miss the train.

Comment: "The boss dragged the meeting out (or "dragged out the meeting") for as long as he could to make us miss the train", where "the meeting" is Od, and hence "dragged" is transitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[To drag out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drag%20out):***

> to cause (something) to take more time than necessary
>
> - He dragged out the speech much too long.

(M-W)

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. 
Do you know any other verb that mean the same thing? Something more formal.

Comment: Look here in the synonyms for prolong: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prolong . I suggest you check each term on the dictionary.